# Java reflection unclarity

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to get a list of objects from the Database based on a target object through reflection.
I don't have much experience with reflection so this doesn't work.
Is it even possible to achieve my goal?

```
public static List<Object> getObjectsFromDataBase(Object targetObj) {
....................
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(queryToExecute);
while (rs.next()) {
     Object obj = new Object();
     for (Field property : targetObj.getClass().getFields()) {
      property.set(obj, rs.getString(property.getName()));
     }
     objListToReturn.add(obj);
}
.....................
return objListToReturn;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  What is `rs`?

Comment: `rs` is clearly a JDBC `ResultSet`

Comment: You need to tell us _how_ it's not working -- i.e. what you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: That is really an incredibly bad idea even when you get it to work. Ignoring the overhead of using reflection you're trying to tie an object's internal design to the column names in a DB table. Why not just use a `Map<String, String>` and avoid all that tight coupling and complexity (Or just use Hibernate to do it for you).

Comment: the targetObj.getClass().getFields() is empty, even though there are attributes in the targetObj class

Comment: @Brian Roach What exactly are you referring to with:'ignoring the overhead of using reflection', i don't have that much experience. I don't mind that the attributes names should always have the same name as the columns, I don't use that complex classes in my project

Comment: I would imagine that reflection overhead is probably very small compared to the amount of time it takes to do a database query. But you could always measure it.

Comment: there will be only one call to the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields in the target object's class are not public they won't show up in `getFields()`.  Try this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test
{
    public static class A
    {
        public String field1;
        public String field2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        A a = new A();
        Object b = a;
        for (Field f : b.getClass().getFields())
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

If you remove `public`, `getFields()` returns an empty array.

Comment: As others have commented, this is a very brittle design.  You should find a different way to do this.

Comment: getDeclaredFields() will return you all class fields, including private ones

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, this is possible, but not with the code you provided.  This concept is called Object Relational Mapping and things like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) do this for you.  If you're just learning about reflection that's great too.  You'll probably need a way to map the fields to the properties of the object, whether that's done with convention (matched names), straight code, annotations, or a mapping input file is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems:

1. You are creating `obj` as type `Object`. the first argument of `Field.set()` needs to be the same type (or a subtype) as the class the containing the field. You need to use reflection to create an object of the same type as `targetObj`, by using `obj = targetObj.getClass().newInstance()` (assuming a default constructor is available)
2. Also your problem might be that the `getFields()` method only returns the public fields of the class.

   targetObj.getClass().getFields()

   If you want to get all the fields of the class, you will need to use the getDeclaredFields() method.